# How can i compile bpel and bpm from jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, soa, bpel

i think that maybe it can be done using ant or maven.

But i don't know so much of PBM or PBEL.

Answer (score 0):

BPM and BPEL are just specifications, you need to more concentrate on the implementations. The one implementation that can leverage continuous integration like jenkins is **JBPM** from **Redhat JBoss**. There are some proprietary implementations that makes continuous integration impossible.